# Can't center the div element when the screen width changes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello everyone i was finishing the last touches on my simple math function plotter then when i used developer tools to see how it looks on mobiles i realized that the header text isn't centered like how it is on the normal version (pc screen) so i tried to add some media queries and still doesn't work.(it always goes to the left on the mobile version), by the way initial scale is set to 1.0 in the meta data.
So here is the code and hope u help me

HTML

```
<div id="header-container">
  <p id="header">راسم منحنيات الدوال</P>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#header-container {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -35px;
    width: 100%;
}

#header {
    font-family: Font3;
    font-size: 45px;
  }
```

Also if you want to check the whole application source code visit this codepen post [over here](https://codepen.io/salahmak/full/YzzpQrE)

Note: when u switch to phone view make it fullscreen by clicking twice to see that the text does't stay at the middle.
Thanks

Comment: Your header is always centered according to the width of the viewport. But since the graph that you create has more width than the maximum mobile width you need to scroll to view the graph. When scrolling horizontally the header doesn't remain in the center, this is normal behaviour in case of HTML and CSS. The functionality you are looking for is "Fixing a div upon horizontal scrolling".

Comment: yeah thought about that too but is there any solution for it ? like changing the size of the graph ? (problem is that i need to use javascript to change its size bcs it is from a library and im not sure if i can link media queries to javascript objects properties)

Comment: You will probably need to use javascript to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your header to be centered above the graph at all times then put the graph and the header inside the same div. So that the width for your header is the same as the width for graph in all viewports.

```js
var parameters = {
  target: '#myFunction',
  width: '834',
  height: '540',
  data: [{
      fn: 'x*x',
      color: '',
      derivative: {
        fn: '2*x',
        updateOnMouseMove: true
      }
    },
    {
      fn: 'x*x',
      color: 'red',
      derivative: {
        fn: '2*x',
        updateOnMouseMove: true
      }
    }
  ],
  grid: true,
  yAxis: {
    domain: [-9, 9]
  },
  xAxis: {
    domain: [-7, 7]
  }
};

function plot() {
  let f = document.querySelector("#function").value;
  let color = document.querySelector("#color").value;
  let derivative = document.querySelector("#der").value;
  let f2 = document.querySelector("#function2").value;
  let color2 = document.querySelector("#color2").value;
  let derivative2 = document.querySelector("#der2").value;
  parameters.data[0].fn = f;
  parameters.data[0].color = color;
  parameters.data[0].derivative.fn = derivative;
  parameters.data[1].fn = f2;
  parameters.data[1].color = color2;
  parameters.data[1].derivative.fn = derivative2;
  functionPlot(parameters);
};
plot();
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "Font";
  src: url("Almarai-Regular.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Font2";
  src: url("Cairo-Regular.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Font3";
  src: url("MarkaziText-Regular.ttf");
}

#plot {
  touch-action: none;
  float: left;
}

.layer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 0px;
}

#plotSettings {
  float: right;
  padding: 0px;
}

#func1 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: Font2;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.input {
  width: 110px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px rgb(15, 97, 74) solid;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}

.tableheads {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Font;
  height: 30px;
}

th {
  font-family: Font;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 50px;
}

#header-container {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -35px;
  width: 100%;
}

#header {
  font-family: Font3;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@3/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/function-plot@1/dist/function-plot.js"></script>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="layer">
      <section id="plot">
        <div id="header-container">
          <p id="header">راسم منحنيات الدوال</p>
        </div>
        <div id="myFunction"></div>
      </section>
      <div dir="rtl" id="plot-settings">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>اعدادات المنحنيات</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tableheads">المنحنى الأول</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <section id="func1">
                <label for="function"> دستور الدالة 1 : </label>
                <input id="function" type="text" value="x*x" onchange="plot();" dir="ltr" class="input" />
                <p></p>
                <label for="derivative"> مشتقة الدالة 1 : </label>
                <input type="text" id="der" value="2*x" onchange="plot();" dir="ltr" class="input" />
                <p></p>
                <p></p>
                <label for="color">لون المنحني : </label>
                <input type="color" id="color" onchange="plot();" dir="ltr" />
                <p></p>
              </section>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="tableheads">المنحنى الثاني</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <section id="func1">
                <label for="function"> دستور الدالة 2 : </label>
                <input id="function2" type="text" value="x^3" onchange="plot();" dir="ltr" class="input" />
                <p></p>
                <label for="derivative"> مشتقة الدالة 2 : </label>
                <input type="text" id="der2" value="3*x^2" onchange="plot();" dir="ltr" class="input" />
                <p></p>
                <label for="color">لون المنحني : </label>
                <input type="color" id="color2" onchange="plot();" dir="ltr" value="Red" />
                <p></p>
              </section>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this by adding it in to css

```
p#header {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: From your answer it seems you have not checked the codepen and nor have you tried to understand the exact problem the user is facing. Answering without understanding the question or without any explanation as to how your answer solves the problem does not help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#header-container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: -35px;
    width: fit-content;
}
```

Comment: A codepen for the original code has been provided. Please don't "hit & try" post your answer. Open the code pen try to fix the issue and then provide the correct code as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the right answer is up you should have checked the codepen.